# JQuery No Conflict; Breaks When Merged

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I am having a problem with avoiding conflicts with different versions of jQuery.  I have a menu bar that is pulling is pulling from 1_7_1 and a tab item that is pulling from 1_9_1.  Please let me know if you have any advice for making the page work while using both versions.  They work fine in separate html files, but once combined one overrides the other.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>jQuery Dropdown Menus</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/menu.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.dropmenu-1.1.4.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/menu.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/menu_ie7_and_ie8.css" />
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_conflict = $.noConflict(true);
        </script>
        <script>
        jQuery_conflict(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
        $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- MENU !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->


        <div class="page">
            <header>
            <!--    <a class="logo" href="#"></a> -->
                <nav class="nav_menu">

                    <ul class="dropmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                        <li><a href"#">Lessons</a> 
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href"#">Lesson 1</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href"#">Lesson 2</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href"#">Lesson 3</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href"#">Lesson 4</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href"#">Lesson 5</a> </li>
                                            <li><a href"#">Lesson 6</a> </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Assignments</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tests and Quizzes</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Playlist Creation</a></li>

                    </ul>


                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>







        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-5">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-6">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
                    <p> <iframe width="700" height="394" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ae_DKNwK_ms" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
                    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
                    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-4">
                <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
                    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-5">
                <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
                    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-6">
                <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
                    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
            </div>

            </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: simply don't. don't use them both.

Comment: jQuery is good at backwards compatibility. If you use just the newer one do you run into problems?

Comment: @AlexMarchant, not true, jQuery 1.9. removed a lot of stuff! `live`, `toggle-event`, `browser`...

Comment: @gdoron most of which have been deprecated for a while, I say try it out, if the old script runs with 1.9 that would be a simple solution.

Comment: You've presumably checked for updates to the plugins you're using (specifically whichever one uses jQuery 1.7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because each file with jQuery redefines `$` variable so once there are two versions embedded using `noConflict` doesn't have much sense no more (you have to use noConflict after definition of each jQuery version.

Simply saying, the merged file should look like this:

```
// jQuery 1.7 source code
// ... jQuery 1.7 code ...
var $jQuery17 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
// jQuery 1.9 source code
// .... jQuery 1.9 ...
var $jQuery19 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Later on use `$jQuery17` and `$jQuery19` variables to access (use) each version.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the feedback.  Do I need to handle the jQuery UI as well or just the no conflict in the normal jQuery library?

Comment: You have to handle jQuery UI yourself, and there's no equivalent of noConflict in jQuery UI so it is a bit trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with loading two versions of jQuery, requiring `.noConflict()`, try the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/).

It adds compatibility for removed functions, and also warns you of them so you can work to update your code.

Comment: Any plugin that, the docs of which, include the line 'Stop hitting yourself!' is a good plugin (that should, clearly, be used).

Comment: I wouldn't actually call *using* documented library method `noConflict()` "messing" with it. It's ok to use it if you have need for it.

Comment: @WTK, Of course, but there is certainly no need to include two copies of jQuery if the Migrate plugin does the job.  I will clarify the wording in my answer.